# cakephp retriving values from combobox

Tags: cakephp, combobox

I am populating a combobox with values from an array using the following:

View Code:

```
echo $this->form->input('Price', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$price));
```

however, when i select a value and click on submit and retrieve this value in my view using get,

View Code:

```
$price=$_GET['Price'];
echo $price;
```

This only gives me the index selected. how do i retrieve the value associated with the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say price array has given structure:

```
array('1'=>'1000','2'=>'2000', etc etc);
```

and view has below line

```
echo $this->form->input('Price', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$price));
```

then it is quite obvious that you will get only index in `$_GET['Price'];`

Now if you want value in `$_GET['Price'];` then change your price array

It should be `array('1000'=>'1000','2000'=>'2000', etc etc);` ie value value pair

Now `$_GET['Price'];` will give you value!

Answer (score 0):

If that line:

```
echo $this->form->input('Price', array('type'=>'select','options'=>$price));
```

is really in your controller you are doing something fundamentally wrong.

This isn't right either:

```
$price=$_GET['Price'];
echo $price;
```

Also what's the point in declaring a variable that is not used at all?

```
echo $_GET['Price'];
```

Does the same and is not a good idea either, all output should be passed through Cakes [h()](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/source-function-h.html#160-199) function, a shortcut for html htmlspecialchars() but it does a little more than htmlspecialchars().

You're not following [CakePHPs coding standards](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html). This is the correct way of doing it:

```
// controller
$this->set('prices', $this->Model->getPrices());

// view
echo $this->form->input('price', array('type'=>'select','options'=> $prices)); 

// Controller
// When you submitted the form you can get the data in the controller in the request object
debug($this->request->data['Model']['price']);
```

Seriously, [do the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html). There is so much wrong here that I basically would have to write a complete tutorial for you. The blog tutorial will teach you the basics.

Comment: hey sorry for the mistake...that line appears in my view and not controller. i am passing it to another view. and i need to use the value of price later. hence the variable.

Comment: The form helper generates a structure of data[Model][field] so just do the debug($this->request->data) as I wrote in the controller method  that receives the form and you'll see how it looks like. However, I would recommend you to to do the blog tutorial it covers all of these things.